# Change upload path for Typo3 extension

Tags: typo3

I'm creating a Typo3 extension which is designed to replace another one that is no longer maintained and highly insecure. The new extension uses the old sql schema and works well so far. However, old entries have their images died in

```
uploads/tx_oldext
```

The new one now obviously wants to use it's own  subdirectory of uploads. I don't want that and am looking for a way to make the new extension use the old upload directory instead. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot change the upload folder globally for an extension. Your extension can either generate a new upload folder in its own namespace or not create one, see more on "uploadfolder" in https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ExtensionArchitecture/DeclarationFile/Index.html

But, if you want to change the upload folder for a field in your TCA, you can do that. Just define an "uploadfolder" in the field definition for a group field:

```
'uploadfolder' => 'uploads/tx_myoldext'
```

Comment: You're right, I missed those tca entries. Works like a charm now. Thank you.